# how to set BSImagePickerViewController with Object-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I use `BSImagePickerViewController` in my app, which is made with `Objective-C`, and have a question. I tried to change the `backgroundColor`, it causes error. like this...[image]

However, I download the `BSImagePickerViewController` package, which is made with `Swift`, and change the code like this, it works... [image]

So I suppose it is because I use `Objective-C` ??  anyone can help?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line below. Maybe it will work.

```
[anImagePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: hi Karthik, it doesn't work. Xcode will show error 'no visible interface...'